# Explode DB record into tabular format

Tags: php, mysql, explode

I have a database connected to my site that is recording actions taken by a user on an application we have built. The application holds a number of images, which the user can view and download, and the application tracks, per user, which image they have viewed delimited by a comma

What I want to do is write a PHP script that will allow me to turn this delimited text string into a calculated table format

If the database has example records of:

```
1 | 1-A, 1-B, 2-A, 2-C
2 | 1-A
3 | 1-B, 2-C
4 | 
5 | 1-A, 1-B, 1-C, 2-A
```

To which I wanted to write a script that would be able to output this as:

```
1-A = 3
1-B = 3
1-C = 1
2-A = 2
2-C = 2
```

**(I want to point out, I'm not suggesting that I want to have variables named after each entry, with its calculated total as the value, I'm open to however is best to return this value)**

My first step was to explode each record into an array, but then I wasn't sure as to my next step to turn this into something I can write into a table.

I realise the database is very poorly structured, but unfortunately I haven't written it, and so I have no ability to re-structure the data is stored.

Kind regards

Answer (score 1, accepted):

this should work:

```
<?php
    $values = array  (
                        '1' => '1-A, 1-B, 2-A, 2-C',
                        '2' => '1-A',
                        '3' => '1-B, 2-C',
                        '4' => '',
                        '5' => '1-A, 1-B, 1-C, 2-A'
                    );
    $valueCounts = array();
    foreach($values as $value)
    {
        foreach(explode(', ', $value) as $val)
        {
            if(!key_exists($val, $valueCounts))
            {
                if($val) $valueCounts[$val] = 1;
            }
            else
            {
                $valueCounts[$val]++;
            }
        }
    }
    ksort($valueCounts);
    foreach($valueCounts as $value => $count)
    {
        echo "$value = $count<br />";
    }
?>
```

result:

```
1-A = 3
1-B = 3
1-C = 1
2-A = 2
2-C = 2
```

if you're not sure how to populate the `$values` array, please paste the database code and I will try and incorporate it into the above.

Comment: great, glad to have helped :)